# Group map countries in drop down menu

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, group-by, google-maps-markers

I’m creating a map with some markers and a drop down menu to select them by country. Many markers are in the same country, so my drop down menu ended up having the option for the same country multiple times.
I’m trying to group my markers per country, so the drop down menu have each country only once.
Does anyone know how I can solve this? I’ve tried many things  but I always end up messing up with my code.
Thanks a lot!

```
var markers = [
  {
    "title": 'France',
    "lat": '43.583627',
    "lng": '3.814796 ',
    "description": '<div id="web-info"> <h6><a target="_blank" href="https://www.ipal-formation.com/">Ipal</a></h6><p>Artomatherapy and Essential Oils Training</p></div>',
    "zoom": '5'
  },
  {
    "title": 'France',
    "lat": '46.521448',
    "lng": '6.633112',
    "description": '<div id="web-info"> <h6><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ecole-era.ch/">Ecole Romande d\'Aromathérapie ERA</a></h6><p>Aromatherapy Course</p></div>',
    "zoom": '5'
  }];

function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 9.072264,
      lng: 7.491302
    },
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var markersData = markers[i];
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData.lat, markersData.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      title: markersData.title
    });

    //Added click listener
    (function (marker, markersData) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        infowindow.setContent(markersData.description);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      jQuery("#selectlocation").append('<option value="' + [markersData.lat, markersData.lng, markersData.zoom].join('|') + '">' + markersData.title + '</option>');
      jQuery(document).on('change', '#selectlocation', function () {
        var latlngzoom = jQuery(this).val().split('|');
        var newzoom = 1 * latlngzoom[2],
          newlat = 1 * latlngzoom[0],
          newlng = 1 * latlngzoom[1];
        map.setZoom(newzoom);
        map.setCenter({ lat: newlat, lng: newlng });
      });
    })(marker, markersData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After append you can remove your duplicate country name using `val` with `siblings` like below.

```
$("#selectlocation option").val(function(index, val) {
  $(this).siblings('[value="'+ val +'"]').remove();
});
```

It's remove all duplicate country from dropdown option.

---

*Note: After append on dropdown your option looks like:*

```
 <option value="France" data-lat="'+ markersData.lat +'"> France </option>
```

Use lat, lang and other option with data.

You can easily catch that data value on dropdown change , like below:

```
$('#selectlocation').find(':selected').data('lat');
```

```js
var markers = [{
    "title": 'France',
    "lat": '43.583627',
    "lng": '3.814796 ',
    "description": '<div id="web-info"> <h6><a target="_blank" href="https://www.ipal-formation.com/">Ipal</a></h6><p>Artomatherapy and Essential Oils Training</p></div>',
    "zoom": '5'
  },
  {
    "title": 'Nepal',
    "lat": '44.583627',
    "lng": '3.814796 ',
    "description": '<div id="web-info"> <h6><a target="_blank" href="https://www.ipal-formation.com/">Ipal</a></h6><p>Artomatherapy and Essential Oils Training</p></div>',
    "zoom": '5'
  },
  {
    "title": 'Nepal',
    "lat": '43.583627',
    "lng": '3.814796 ',
    "description": '<div id="web-info"> <h6><a target="_blank" href="https://www.ipal-formation.com/">Ipal</a></h6><p>Artomatherapy and Essential Oils Training</p></div>',
    "zoom": '5'
  },
  {
    "title": 'France',
    "lat": '46.521448',
    "lng": '6.633112',
    "description": '<div id="web-info"> <h6><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ecole-era.ch/">Ecole Romande d\'Aromathérapie ERA</a></h6><p>Aromatherapy Course</p></div>',
    "zoom": '5'
  }
];
$.each(markers, function(index, value) {
  //console.log(value.lat);
  jQuery("#selectlocation").append('<option data-lat="' + value.lat + '" value="' + value.title + '">' + value.title + '</option>');
});
$("#selectlocation option").val(function(index, val) {
  $(this).siblings('[value="' + val + '"]').remove();
});
jQuery(document).on('change', '#selectlocation', function() {
  var lat = $(this).find(':selected').data('lat');
  console.log(lat);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectlocation">

</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shree! I’ll try as soon as I get home! I have many other contries still to enter, is this going to work if I add other contries?

Comment: You’re a star! Tonight I’ll let you know how it went!